# "Error: failed to post funding tx" on metaplex

Tags: node.js, reactjs, solana, nft, metaplex

I am trying to upload solana NFT metadata to arweave.net.
I tried below code.

```
      await METAPLEX
        .nfts()
        .update({
            name: newName,
            nftOrSft: nft,
            uri: metadataUri
        }, { commitment: 'finalized' });
```

And this is error.

> Error: failed to post funding tx -
> 4tSgRoDyCwaT9DwK8GsnMTPeYfPZCwi4W3tpiTeei1H7WBZ9LEbbPthRaLBLXzGqLVoQQmwqmXpZd7ciKwHH3gCw
> (keep this id!) - Fund Tx Not Found

I tried several but all not working.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fix that issue by adding `nftStorage` in metaplex

Here is modified code

```
const METAPLEX = Metaplex.make(connection)
.use(keypairIdentity(wallet))
.use(bundlrStorage({
    address: 'https://devnet.bundlr.network',
    providerUrl: rpcUrl,
    timeout: 60000,
}))
.use(nftStorage());
```

This removes the errors.

Comment: Where can I import `nftStorage`?

Comment: You can import `nftStorage()` like below. `import { nftStorage } from "@metaplex-foundation/js-plugin-nft-storage";
`

Comment: Actually, for now, it is deprecated and now you can use `umi` for this.

Answer (score 2):

I experience the same problem before. My problem was I have been using Solana Devnet. But use below code for bundlrStorage.

```
const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection)
.use(keypairIdentity(wallet))
.use(bundlrStorage());
```

However, according Metaplex's doc, the default setting is for mainnet connection. Thus, I amend this part to below:

```
const METAPLEX = Metaplex.make(connection)
.use(keypairIdentity(wallet))
.use(bundlrStorage({
    address: 'https://devnet.bundlr.network',
    providerUrl: rpcUrl,
    timeout: 60000,
}));
```

Hope it helps.